# Is this closet wall load bearing?

Tags: load-bearing, renovation

Wanting to remove this closet that is by my front door. Nervous that the wall that is parallel to the door is wall bearing. First time renovating.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdXz4.jpg[image][image]

Comment: Do you know what is in the attic directly above the walls?can you take a picture?

Comment: I have added what it looks like directly above.

Comment: what is the brick-looking platform in front of the former closet?

Answer (score 4):

From the 2 images you've attached, this is not a load bearing group of walls. Feel free to remove all 3 of them.

Comment: I would agree not a load bearing wall.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the assist!

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect more blocking in a load-bearing wall (more than none)

Corners always have lots of wood, but the purpose of that is just to provide somewhere to attach the lining.

Comment: What is “lining”?

Comment: It's the stuff that hides the studs:  drywall, or wood paneling etc.

Answer (score 1):

Even without the attic picture, I would find it very, very unusual that any of these three walls are load bearing. It would be many times more unusual for the wall -parallel- to your front door (thus parallel to your roof framing) to be bearing.

Your attic picture shows that the roof is bearing on a continuous wall which is the exterior wall. There would be some very obvious change in the roof framing at the area of the closet walls if they were to be bearing walls.

To be most clear and direct: your closet walls are not bearing walls